# SendGrid v3 400 bad request

Tags: php, sendgrid

I'm using **sendgrid/sendgrid-php** [the repo on github](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php) to send transnational emails. Today I've updated the library, the new one uses the API v3 whereas I used v2 before. I've changed the code as per their examples, here is a dump of my SendGrid\Mail object:

[image]

The problem is that I'm constantly receiving the 400 BAD REQUEST error without any additional info:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? The mail object seems to be correct.

I'm trying to send the email the following way:

```
$apiKey = getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY');
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);
$request_body = [creating the mail object];
$response = $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($request_body);
```

Comment: Just to be clear, does [creating the mail object]; mean new SendGrid\Mail($from, $subject, $to, $content); ? Or are you doing without the Helper class?

Comment: @JustinSteele I use the helper as per this example https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/examples/helpers/mail/example.php, see the kitchenSink function. I.e. I first create the mail object, then add emails, personalisations and attachments and invoke $sg->client->mail()->send()->post($mail); finally

Comment: I don't think the `custom_args` param takes a JSON array. I think it should be a JSON object. Like this:  `{"md_email_id":26921}`. This might be an issue with the library. It could be useful to show how you're building the email object.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and discovered all personalizations need to be strings with double quotes.  In your example:

```
$md_email_id = (string)26921
```

More info https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/issues/264